Can one easily jam an UWB-inter-drone link?
How jamming resistant is UWB communication?
What is the effective range of UWB jamming (i.e. up to what distance around a jammer is a UWB communication impossible?)
Is UWB jamming currently usual in Ukraine?

Asking about jamming really isn't on-topic for our forum here. Perhaps the flipside would, though, in asking how to defend against it. (less of a weapon)
